# Android Intents and Scala

Tags: android, scala, android-intent

I am attempting to convert the following tutorial, http://savagelook.com/blog/android/swipes-or-flings-for-navigation-in-android, into Scala code for android.  I have everything working well, except for MyGestureDetector class which I have not yet completed but already have errors in.  My code is as follow

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
  override def onFling(e1:MotionEvent, e2:MotionEvent, velocityX:Float, velocityY:Float):Boolean ={
  var intent:Intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this.getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class)

  true  
} 

override def onDown(e:MotionEvent):Boolean = {
  true
} 
}
```

My code is giving me a red underline on the MainActivity.this.getBaseContext() and the MainActivity.class.  The red x next to the line says that MainActivity is not an enclosing class, that an identifier was expected but .class found, and that MainActivity is not a value. I am importing the following packages

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.GestureDetector
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
```

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?? Thank you all

Michael

Comment: Try `classOf[MainActivity]` instead of `MainActivity.class`.

Comment: That worked on the var intent:Intent = new Intent (classOf[MainActivity].getBaseContext(), classOf[MainActivity]) second argument.  I still have a red line under the getBaseContext portion... any suggestions?

Comment: In case of doubt, try to compile. If it works, the red line is wrong.

Comment: Same in java as in scala, your class has to be nested inside MainActivity.

Comment: I think I've figured it out, the redlines are gone.  I'm going to test it now.  Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.:

```
val myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, classOf[DestinationActivity])
```

The first parameter should be the instance of the current activity. ( Since Activity extends Context, and the current Context is needed)